# Does the server "shut down" when the browser is closed? PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, apache, http, lamp

I was wondering - as I wrote a snippet of code that could update up to 10,000 rows and might take a few seconds to complete, if when the file is accessed via an ajax request, the post query is send to the php file, then the browser is closed, does the file get fully executed? assume it takes about 25 seconds to complete the request, the user might not wait for 25 seconds, is good enough to "ping" this file and let the user browse along or close its browser window as the mysql queries are taking place?

Comment: just a guess, but i would say that once the command was send, the browsers work is done. Similiar to a print job maybe: you can close the picture, the image is printed as well

Answer (score 2):

The request has 3 parts

1. A browser connected to the web server
2. PHP script that is executed by the server
3. A query running in the DB server

When you close the browser, connection with the server is closed. The server may or may not kill the started PHP script (if PHP is running as apache module, it would be killed, unless ignore_user_abort is called). Also the web server may have a time limit for the request and either kill the script or just send the client a connection timeout message, without killing the script, but without giving it the chance to send anything to the browser.

Here is the tricky part - the update is running in the database and it won't be killed by the web server, neither by PHP.

So what you want to achieve is pinging a PHP script, that is executing a query, but the client do not wait the result. You may or may not want the query itself to be asyncronous (the PHP script not to wait the query), but you  have to tell the client that the request is fulfilled, by sending content-length of 0 for example, and flushing the output (the http headers actually), and running PHP with ignore_user_abort so it continues the execution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ignore-user-abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) to continue running the script even after the client has disconnected

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

You can use [connection_status](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php) to track if the connection has disconnected

```
if (connection_status()!=0) { //connection disconnected
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer for your question:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 0):

Normally no, but your script pass in `ABORTED` status.

More details in the manual page about **Connection handling**:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

> Internally in PHP a connection status is maintained. There are 3
>   possible states:
>
> 0 - NORMAL
>
> 1 - ABORTED
>
> 2 - TIMEOUT
>
> When a PHP script is running normally the NORMAL state, is active. If
>   the remote client disconnects the ABORTED state flag is turned on. A
>   remote client disconnect is usually caused by the user hitting his
>   STOP button.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you close the browser, it disconnects from the server before getting the reply. I do not know exactly how different servers behave in this condition but I assume that most of the server will abort the thread that they are working on to reply the request.

Further, things can be different with different operations - i.e. file i/o or database operation. If it is an atomic database operation, my assumption is, it will complete any how.

Comment: But OP didn't ask for assumptions (and you know what they [say about them](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc)). Please refer to the manual, don't guess.